# Set Databricks Permissions via API

Tags: databricks, databricks-rest-api

The [Databricks spec](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/permissions/set) introduces how to create permissions via an REST API.
There, two path parameters are described: `request_object_type`, `request_object_id`. Unfortunately no examples are given for them. Where/How do I get those parameters from assuming that I want to set the permissions for a git **Repo**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it

```
PATCH /api/2.0/permissions/repos/{RepoID}
```